# AWS codebuild error: "found duplicate source location for secondary source"

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm working on a CI/CD AWS lambda. A build step in my pipeline takes the template and produces an output template with a reference to the new source code. This works when the original template is stored in with the source code for the lambda, but it is problematic because then I need two copies of the original template (one in my cloudformation git repo, one with the lambda source code). I've already had a bug once where I updated one copy of the template and forgot to update the other. It seems straightforward to have the pipeline download the lambda from S3 instead of keeping it in git, but when I do I get a strange error in the DOWNLOAD_SOURCE phase of CodeBuild:

```
CLIENT_ERROR: found duplicate source location for secondary source LambdaTemplate
```

I can't figure out what is going on here. What does this error even mean? I have other pipelines that use secondary sources in exactly the same way with no problems. This error happens before my buildspec even runs, so it isn't an error there. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused because in the source config you have used a non-zipped file.

Just change the input source to file.zip and zip the file before you upload in s3. CodeBuild only accepts zipped files. The error is not helpful as it does not tell you the exact problem.

[image]

Comment: This seems promising, except that all my inputs are from AWS codecommit. The zip/don't zip isn't even an option there, it is always zipped...right?

Comment: The file you are getting from. S3 may be causing it. Just try zipping that file before uploading to s3. It will be unzipped for you automatically in the pipeline steps.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the file you are getting from S3". As I said in my previous comment, when I try to do this, there are no files coming in through S3. They are all coming from AWS codecommit.

Answer (score 0):

If you CodeBuild action configuration in the pipeline is taking multiple source inputs, can you check if the names of the input artifacts are not the same:

```
{
  "name": "Build",
  "actions": [
    {
      "inputArtifacts": [
        {
          "name": "source1"             <================ Check this 
        },
        {
          "name": "source2"             <================ and this 
        }
      ],
      "name": "Build",
      "actionTypeId": {
        "category": "Build",
        "owner": "AWS",
        "version": "1",
        "provider": "AWS CodeBuild"
      },
      "outputArtifacts": [
        {
          "name": "artifact1"
        },
        {
          "name": "artifact2"
        }
      ],
      "configuration": {
        "ProjectName": "my-build-project-name",
        "PrimarySource": "source1"
      },
      "runOrder": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

],

Complete reference is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-pipeline-multi-input-output.html

Comment: I checked, I don't have any duplicate names. It's strange.

I worked around the problem by using "aws s3 cp ..." in my buildspec.yml to get the file that I needed, but I'd prefer to make it a pipeline input.